# I can't see all static cells on my Interface Builder

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, xcode4.2

Ok maybe this is a stupid question, but really I don't know what I'm missing.

I'm using Xcode 4.2 with UiTableView and I'm trying to use static cells. Everything is ok if I just use a few cells. But when I try to use a lot of cells, I can't edit the cells that i can't see in the interface builder.

And I really don't know how to show them !!  I've been looking for the answer but all the examples I've seen use only 4 or 5 cells..!!

Can somebody help me with this, maybe I just need to modify some attribute? its so weird that I can't see and modify all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could scroll down to them... Just click on the uitableview on interface builder and scroll down with the mouse or trackpad... that should show you the remaining cells and allow you to edit

Answer (score 0):

Try scrolling first in the editor and if that doesn't work.  Check out [Can't scroll to the bottom of a long Static TableViewController in XCode 5 Interface Builder to edit the cells below the fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964823/cant-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-long-static-tableviewcontroller-in-xcode-5-inter)