# Can't scroll to the bottom of a long Static TableViewController in XCode 5 Interface Builder to edit the cells below the fold

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode5

in XCode 5 Interface Builder, when I select a Static TableViewController that has a lot of rows in it, I can get it to go below the fold for a cell and half but the scrolling stops there.  What's the trick to go all the way down to the bottom to edit/design the bottom static cells that are below the fold in interface builder?

Comment: After some playing with it.  I've noticed that it is only a problem if I have multiple sections.   So if I have 10 rows in the first section, I can select any row in the first section.  Then right click scroll to the bottom of that section.  I just can't scroll into the second section.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to uncheck the options "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars" of Attributes Inspector / View Controller / Extend Edges. I can scroll into the others sections.

Comment: Great for editing in IB, although you'd want to check that again before building if you do want your controller to still scroll under.

Comment: I hope everyone who upvoted this has already filed a radar about this issue.