# How to scroll UITableView in Storyboard editor of Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, xcode5

Storyboard had great feature to design tables of static cells.
Until XCode 5 is was possible to compose long list of cells and scroll the table to edit them.

With XCode 5 the scrolling simple stopped working - instead of scrolling the table, now it scrolls entire the storyboard.

Did anyone solved this problem?
I'm completely stuck with my long tables of static cells...

Comment: UPDATE: When I convert the storyboard back to 4.6 format scrolling start working normally in XCode 5. But in 5.0 mode it stopping working again.

Comment: I'm not sure of your comfort level but if you're familiar with xml you could open a copy of both file versions (6/7) in source code mode (or with a diff editor) and look at what is happening under the hood (it's fairly readable). Something is not correct in the conversion and should be reported as a bug to Apple. I would test this under Xcode 5.0.1 as it is the latest version and the bug might be fixed.

Answer (score 47):

In the storyboard view uncheck Under Top Bars with the problematic scroll view selected.

This allowed me to scroll all the way down.

This only occurred in one of my views, so still not sure what it happens.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just tried it in my XCode 5. After selecting one of the other not covered table cells I am able to scroll down to the other hidden table cells. Does this work for you too?

Similar post, maybe this helps you too:

[Can't scroll to the bottom of a long Static TableViewController in XCode 5 Interface Builder to edit the cells below the fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964823/cant-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-long-static-tableviewcontroller-in-xcode-5-inter)

Comment: Nope, is doesn't work for me. I've tried to select everything - cell, section, table - no luck. It still scrolls the storyboard, not the table.

Comment: The only scrolling that I can do in XCode 5 is 3.5-retina-mode - when I select 3.5-retina mode, I can slightly scroll the table, but only to edge that I can see in  4-retina mode.

Comment: That's strange. I'm using it in the 4-retina-mode and its working. Which XCode 5 Version do you have? I got the following: Version 5.0 (5A1413)

Comment: I have exactly 5.0 (5A1413).

Comment: I've just login under different user and created test project in environment with clean XCode settings - it works there.

Comment: So, this is not XCode 5 'by design', it's bug and I'm trying to fugue out when it happens...

Comment: Strange. Maybe during the IOS 6 -> IOS 7 storyboard conversion went something wrong.

Comment: Try selecting some cell or headerView/footerView in your controller (not tableView itself). In my case it was not working when selecting tableView :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps that I have found to work:

1. Select the TableViewController in the Document Outline (view to the
   left of the Storyboard).
2. Click on the Status Bar (or somewhere along the top) of the
   TableViewController so that the entire TableViewController is
   selected in the Storyboard View.
3. Use the scroll wheel on your mouse or the "2-finger scroll" on the
   trackpad.

The scroll bars on the side of the Storyboard View only seem to move the storyboard around.

It also only seems to work if the mouse pointer is hovering over the TableViewController.

Using Xcode 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: You are a legend. I have been tearing my hair out over this!

Comment: @CharlesRobertson Thanks!