# UITableView Partially Blank in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, xcode7

When trying to view a larger UITableView inside of a UIViewController in the storyboard, I can only see/edit the top most cells from the table. The moment I scroll further down the cells are all blank. This is purely for storyboard, the code works fine when running, but any cells in the storyboard that are further down a tableview I can no longer edit since they show as blank.

[Here's an example to illustrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pES7U.png)

As can be seen from the shift right click, I can't even select the cells that are there.

I know and have experienced problems such as not being able to scroll at all before, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029893/how-to-scroll-uitableview-in-storyboard-editor-of-xcode-5), but this is different as I can scroll down but cannot see the rest of the cells of my tableview. Has anyone else ran into this problem, and would know a solution? It seems like it may have something to do with Xcode 7, as I recently upgraded to it.

Comment: ok...so you are not able to see text & images when you are scrolling down. Right? Please check for autolayout constraint if have set earlier. If you adding imageView & label for text then please also check frame. I would suggest you to provide "CellForRowAtIndexPath" code that you wrote.

Comment: Are there any views other than the tableview in your view controller's view?

Comment: This is purely on the storyboard, so none of the code matters as far as I'm aware. The tableview was the only thing in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal, I've found a few work arounds for this problem. One solution is to make a temporary UIViewController with a UITableView, and then drag cells into the temp UIViewController until the cell you want to edit is visible. Once you've changed it, drag all the cells in the temporary view controller back into their correct controller. This is extremely hacky, but so far is the only way I've found to visibly see the cell.

Another thing that can be done is that the cells are still editable in the document outline, meaning constraints and elements can still be modified from there. However, it is difficult, as I wasn't able to see the cells being edited, they still appear to be blank.

Hopefully someone else finds/knows of a solution to this and can post it, I'll leave these two workarounds up though they're far from ideal.

Comment: An easier way to edit is to drag the "blank" cells up into the viewable default portion, and close/re-open the project. I'm having the same problem and it's extremely frustrating.