# xcode 7 / Storyboard UITableview with many prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7, xcode-storyboard

I m new with storyboard.
I try to add several prototype cells inside a UITableView, but I can't figure out how to scroll the UITableview to add another one.
In my example, I have a Prototype Cell with a height that exceeds the place reserved for the prototype cells..
Is there a way to scroll the tableview to show/add the prototype cells or adjust the storyboard scene?

[image]

Comment: You can exchange the prototype cells if have hard time scrolling down (yes, I've scrolled down few times but still can't figure out the way it works).

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the answer from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029893/how-to-scroll-uitableview-in-storyboard-editor-of-xcode-5