# Can't scroll to the bottom of UIViewController XCode 5 Interface Builder to edit or add object below the fold

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an UIViewController and I can not fit all my design elements from the Object Library in Interface Builder. When working with storyboard, I need to be able to scroll on the UIViewController so I can see the top of the design and the rest of the design below the fold.

The following allows scrolling with static tables but did not have any luck with the UIViewController...

- Try to uncheck the options "Under Top Bars" and "Under Bottom Bars"
  of Attributes Inspector / View Controller / Extend Edges.

My question is similar to the following but does not work UIViewController: 
[Can't scroll to the bottom of a long Static TableViewController in XCode 5 Interface Builder to edit the cells below the fold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964823/cant-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-long-static-tableviewcontroller-in-xcode-5-inter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way to resize UIViewController and incorporate the UIScrollView.

Laying Out a UIScrollView in Interface Builder:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18

Answer (score 0):

I can increase `UIViewController` size in storyboard after changeing *Size* attribute to *Freeform* in *Attributes Inspector*, when controller is selected.

It's working on `UITableViewController` and `UIViewController`. You have to select table or view to change it's size after selecting *Freeform* on controller.